# How to associate your app's Twitter account with a user's Twitter share (post) from your app?

Tags: ios, twitter

My app allows users to share photos that were created by the app to their Twitter accounts. I have implemented this Twitter functionality using the `Accounts Framework` and `SLRequest`.

This works perfectly. However, I would like to make it so that my app's Twitter account is attached to every post that is generated by my app when a user wants to share a photo.

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

Notice that right underneath "My girlfriend!", there is a small icon that has "Frontback" next to it. If you click on "Frontback" it will take you to their Twitter page.

I would like my app to do the same thing. I have looked through the Twitter `REST API` resources [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1), but have not found anything for what I am trying to accomplish.

EDIT:

Here is a sample of my Twitter sharing code:

```
NSDictionary *message = @{ @"status": self.twitterStatus};

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com" @"/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];

SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter 
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST  
                                                      URL:requestURL parameters:message];                   
postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

[postRequest addMultipartData:self.imageData
                     withName:@"media[]"
                         type:@"image/jpeg"
                     filename:@"image.jpg"];

[postRequest setAccount:postRequest.account];
```

And then I call `performRequestWithHandler` on `postRequest` to perform the request and post to Twitter.

Comment: I think that happens automatically when you use your app ID with the API.

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I didn't even realize Twitter had a dev sign in where you can add an app because I never needed it to share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your app ID while using the Twitter API and posts from your app will automatically be tagged with the link and icon of your app.

Comment: Please see the code that I added. Do you know what I need to add to it? I have viewed all of the relevant API pages for uploading media and there are no parameters for including an app id. Is it not possible using my code? Is the only way to use something like the Twitter Cards?

Comment: @user3344977 You use your app ID when authenticating with Twitter.

Comment: "You use your app ID when authenticating with Twitter" Is that when I call requestForServiceType ?

Comment: @user3344977 These questions are going off-topic from your original question. Please ask a new question about other issues you're facing.

Comment: Please see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975862/how-to-include-twitter-app-id-when-posting-to-twitter-via-ios-app